# Angular search for combined key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Say you have the following object:

```
var user: {firstname: 'Marc', lastname:'Ras', age:30};
```

You have alot of these objects in an array called: `user_array`

Now you wish to display them in a table so you create your table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Full name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in user_array">
      <td>{{user.firstname + ' '+user.lastname}}</td>
      <td>{{user.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now you wish to create an input field where you can search for a user's full name:

And here is kinda ends for me :S how is it possible to search for a combinded key? normally you would have:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.fieldname" />
```

However you cant do that here since the field is combined of two `fieldnames`?

Comment: Create a custom filter

Comment: @PatrickReck Can you give an example?

Comment: For instance you want to type "Marc Ras" in the field and then there is a research for that full name ?

You may have to write a bit of javascript to parse the data written (the full name writed) and then make that research.

You got the split method for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your controller

```
 $scope.filterNameLastName = function (user) {
          var fullname = user.firstname + ' '+ user.lastname;
          if(fullname == $scope.searchParamater)
             return true;
          else
             return false;
        };
```

and add filter to ng-repeat

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Full name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in user_array | filter:filterNameLastName ">
      <td>{{user.firstname + ' '+user.lastname}}</td>
      <td>{{user.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This should give you an idea on how custom filters work. I haven't tested the code so you may have to do some modifications.